# Showing that a linear transformation is injective, surjective or bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am doing the following problem for practice to understand linear transformations.

> Consider the linear transformation $T:P_2 \rightarrow P_2$ defined by:
>   $$ T(p(x)) = p(x+1) $$
>   Where $P_2$ is the vector space of polynomials of at most degree 2. Determine whether T is injective, surjective, or bijective.

The problem I am having trouble on how to start this. Just from using my intuition I would say that the $T$ is bijective partially because it is going from one vector space to the same vector space. But I am unsure of how to show this. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 'Just from using my intuition I would say that $T$ is bijective partially because it is going from one vector space to the same vector space.' So, using your intuition, the map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\to0$ is also bijective?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Here's a start: to check whether $T$ is injective, assume that $T(p) = T(q)$. What's that tell you about $p$ and $q$ an their relationship to each other? If this, through your knowledge of algebra, implies that $p = q$, then $T$ is injective.

[This technique is really quite general: it's what you should first do whenever you try to prove something's injective, unless you know quite a lot more (e.g., you know it's a matrix transformation with full rank, ...)]

Answer (score 0):

Injectivity: Show that $T(p)(x)=0$ for all $x$ $\Leftrightarrow p(x)=0$ for all x.

Surjectivity: Show that for every $q\in P_2$ there is $p\in P_2$ such that $T(p)(x)=q(x)$ for every $x$.

Note: Since $P_2$ is finite-dimensional, it is enough to show one of these.